# I try to use *ngIf to display and hgide dome words with a button, but ngIf does not work

Tags: angular

Here is my code.

app.component.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>toogleTag</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div *ngIf="display">

      <p>Toogle by click</p>

  </div>

  <button (click)="toogleTag()">Toogle Tag</button>

</body>

</html>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  display:boolean=false;
  ngOnInit(){
  }
  toogleTag(){
    this.display=!this.display;
  }
}
```

I design a porperty: display to show the div or not, and use ngIf, but ngIf is not work, I dont know why.

Comment: Viking, in an app.component you do **not** use html--body. Angular create the index with this tags. In your components you write only the "inner". think in Angular as a BIG `<div>....</div>` inside a .html. I suggest you take a tour for the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: All my bad, I'm not start serve in terminal

Answer (score 0):

Move everything that is not in the body out of app.component.html and into index.html

Inside the index.html, you should have the HTML, head, body, etc.

Inside body you should only have AppComponent selector, in this case app-root.

```
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Look at how it's structured when you execute:

ng new (project-name)

Comment: All my bad, I'm not start serve in terminal